# Multiple functions one after the other in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am quite new to javascript so I wanted to ask a question because I find the question online.
In javascript, the syntax for functions is:

```
object.function();
```

I get an error when I try to make the function:

```
this.cell = hlist.shift().join(' ');
```

**where hlist is an array, containing strings in each index**

I am trying to remove the first element of the array and then create one whole string with what is left.

Thank you

Comment: you can do that ^^ :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs um.... it is called chaining.... so yes you can do that

Comment: Yes, that's possible. What you've written is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @epascarello didn't know that's what it was called :D but yeah thats what I said - it can be done haha

Comment: I know there are dues on this, just can not find a decent one.

Comment: But for some reason, when i run the code, it seems to come up with an error saying it isn't a function?

Comment: @JunhoChoi What is the actual code you are running? You can not just put a function name, you need to code it to be chainable.

Comment: @JunhoChoi that happens when a function returns nothing or undefined. Be sure that every function returns something.

Comment: This is the exact code I'm running:

Comment: this.cell = hlist[i].toLowerCase().slice(1).join(' ').shift();

Comment: `join` returns a string, strings don't have a `shift` method.

Comment: LOL, I thought you were asking how to code a method so it it chainable, not why that line of methods was not working.

Comment: Oh that explains it ok. Would I then have to convert that string (returned from join) into an array to apply the shift function?

Comment: What is the purpose of shift? what is the actual string you have, what is the expected outcome? That is what should be in your actual question. "I have the string XXXXXXXXXX and I want it to be YYYYYY. This is what I tried ZZZZZZZZZZZ.

Comment: Why would you first `join` an array into a string to then turn it into an array again to `shift` it? Do you have a clear purpose for what you're trying to do, or are you just concatenating random actions?

Comment: shift is to remove the first elemnt of an array. So what i've done s put hift where slice was and remove slice

Comment: I'm putting an array (which contains strings as elements) into a string in itself and removing the index accompanied with each string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/476), here's the answer to what you're *actually* trying to accomplish:

```
this.cell = hlist.slice(1).join(' ');
```

Create a new array omitting the first element, and join it.

Comment: My apologies but to be fair, my initial question was not a XY question and I was asking about the problem itself, or at least what I thought the problem was at the time. Thank you